# How to deserialize this dynamic keys JSON to Java custom Pojo using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, mongo-jackson-mapper

I have a pretty complex json string that I would like to deserialize into custom Java Pojo, but Im not so sure how to do it.

Here is the json:

```
{
   "A": {
          "view": {

                   "1": ["stringA", "stringB"],
                   "2": ["stringA", "stringB"],
                   "3": ["stringA", "stringB"]
                  },
           "list": ["stringA", "StringB"]
         },
   "B": {
         "view": {

                   "1": ["stringA", "stringB"],
                   "2": ["stringA", "stringB"],
                   "3": ["stringA", "stringB"]
                  },
           "list": ["stringA", "StringB"]
         }
}
```

Notice that `view` key has an extra nesting comparing to `list`.

Any help would be great!

**EDIT2:**

Let's try to reduce my question into a simpler JSON as follow:

```
{
   "view": {

              "1": ["stringA", "stringB"],
              "2": ["stringA", "stringB"],
              "3": ["stringA", "stringB"]
           },
   "list": ["stringC", "stringD"]
}
```

Here is my Pojo:

```
public class Model {

   private final Map<String, List<String> modelView;
   private final List<String> modelList;

   @JsonCreator
   public ModelView(@JsonProperty("view") Map<String, List<String>> 
   modelView, @JsonProperty("list") List<String> modelList) {
     this.modelView = modelView;
     this.modelList = modelList;
   }

   public Map<String, List<String>> getModelView() {
     return modelView;
   }
   
   public List<String> getModelList() {
     return modelList;
   }
}
```

and my test code:

```
 @Test
  public void testSerialization() throws Exception {

    try {

      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json1Str());

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

      Model model = mapper.readValue(json.toString(), Model.class);

      System.out.println(model.getModelView());

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

It doesn't work...any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize the JSON with dynamic keys you can use the [@JsonAnySetter](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#:%7E:text=3.3.%20%40-,JsonAnySetter,-%40JsonAnySetter%20allows%20us) annotation from the Jackson library. It will add your keys to values mapping into the Java Map.

```
public class DyanamicJson {

    private Map<String, Object> dynamicKeys = new HashMap<>();
    
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setUnknownFields(String name, Object value) {
        dynamicKeys.put(name, value);
    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> getFieldsMap() {
        return dynamicKeys;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I would like my Pojo to be a model class of the JSON so I can then access its data easily.

Comment: Added "EDIT 1" to the original question above.

Comment: As your question heading says, How to deserialize this **dynamic keys JSON** to Java custom Pojo using Jackson. So I suggested the above approach. Can you please add the exception?

Comment: Updated "EDIT 2" which presents a solution to the nested structure and it works well. Only left to do is to model the top level nesting (e.g: "A", "B" in the original question)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final model class, hoping this would help someone...

```
public class LangModel {

   private final Map<String, Model> langModel;

   @JsonCreator
   public LangMode(Map<String, Model> langModel) {
      this.langModel = langModel;
   }

   public LangModel getLangModel() {
      return langModel;
   }

   public static class Model {

     private final Map<String, List<String> modelView;
     private final List<String> modelList;

     @JsonCreator
     public ModelView(@JsonProperty("view") Map<String, List<String>> 
     modelView, @JsonProperty("list") List<String> modelList) {
       this.modelView = modelView;
       this.modelList = modelList;
     }

     public Map<String, List<String>> getModelView() {
       return modelView;
     }
   
     public List<String> getModelList() {
       return modelList;
     }
   }
}
```